# Is there an automatic way to fit this piece perfectly?

Tags: modeling, objects, axis

I'm trying to create an apple monster character and later on he'll be used in an experimental video game environment. I'm having a problem with this apple piece, I want it to fit perfectly in the hole, it was a perfect fit with the other piece on the left, because the 3D cursor placement stayed the same. I rotated the piece towards 3D cursor's X axis, and typing in 75 for angle. I have a lot of manual "auto-saves", so if it's impossible to fix it on this file, I can go back to that step where the pieces were cut, but didn't have any movement affection.

[image]

**The pieces were not scaled nor moved, only rotated.**

[image]

I thought of trying to fix it by "Alt + G"-ing, but a lot of objects scattered around, "Alt + R" no luck too and pretty much I'm out of ideas. And just in case, these pieces will be have to be riggable for animation.

Comment: why don't you select both the piece and your apple, go in Edit mode and move the piece vertices so that they stick to the apple?

Comment: @moonboots Do you mean by rotating the piece manually to that point when it fits perfectly? That's time consuming and I hoped for some automatic feature for it.

Comment: you rotate it as best as possible, then bring some correction manually with the snap to vertices option enabled so that the vertices of the piece stick to the vertices of the apple, but maybe i don't understand everything you explained...

Comment: @moonboots snapping did work, but again it took some time. I updated the question, should be a lot clearer now.